# Can't install mgba python module

Tags: python-3.x, linux, module, raspberry-pi, emulation

I installed mgba (which works) by activating the use of python, I tried to import the mgba module but it does not exist, I also checked where my modules are stored, so I went to the folder  `/src/platform/python` and made: `python3 setup.py install`.
Unfortunately I get this error:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing mgba.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to mgba.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to mgba.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to mgba.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'mgba.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'mgba.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-aarch64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/mgba._pylib.c'
already up-to-date
building 'mgba._pylib' extension
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/mgba._pylib.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/mgba._pylib.o -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/..
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /home/pi/build/src/platform/python/vfs-py.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/vfs-py.o -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/..
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /home/pi/build/src/platform/python/core.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/core.o -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/..
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /home/pi/build/src/platform/python/log.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/log.o -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/..
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /home/pi/build/src/platform/python/sio.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/sio.o -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../../../include -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/../.. -I/home/pi/build/src/platform/python/..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    "Topic :: System :: Emulators"
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 24, in run
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 144, in run
    base_class.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
    _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 199, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 559, in build_extension
    target_lang=language)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 717, in link_shared_object
    extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 170, in link
    libraries)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 1092, in gen_lib_options
    opt = compiler.runtime_library_dir_option(dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 264, in runtime_library_dir_option
    return "-Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R" + dir
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Do you have any idea what it is due to ? I have correctly compiled mgba and the module, and there was no error on it.  Moreover I don't see where the error comes from

Comment: ` + dir` fails because dir is undefined, ie "NoneType".   It probably expects a library dir parameter or environment variable to be set somewhere.  Looks like the directory in which to store the result.

Comment: Finnaly, I have moved path to python module path and it work